# How to serve embedded resource from a dynamically loaded assembly with something like WebResource.axd

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

The background here is, I am developing a plugin for a CMS which is loaded via reflection from an external assembly. I want to embed some javascript and CSS files into my assembly so that I can load those files inside the CMS.

Ordinarily, you'd use `Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(Type type, string resourceName)` and the resulting URL points to `WebResource.axd`, whose job it is to find the correct assembly, locate the correct resource and stream it back to the client.

This works fine if the assembly is already loaded as part of your application (e.g. it exists in your bin folder), but in this case it won't work because my assembly is only ever loaded via reflection (i.e. `Assembly.Load()`) from an external directory. The WebResource handler won't be able to find the assembly and so requests of this type will always result in a 404.

My question is, is there an accepted and well-trodden way of doing what I'm trying to achieve here or am I going to have to roll my own? Bear in mind, simply putting the assembly in the bin folder is not an option here.

I've tried google and searching here and I can find people with the same problem I'm experiencing, but no solutions as yet.

Oh, I should add, I'm running on .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0):

You should load all of your plugin assemblies eagerly using BuildManager's [AddReferencedAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildmanager.addreferencedassembly%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method.

This can be achieved at application start by utilizing the [PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.preapplicationstartmethodattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Then whenever you need to discover your types use [GetReferencedAssemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildmanager.getreferencedassemblies%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).